# CiviCRM error in email cronjob

Tags: wordpress, civicrm

When I run this command from the command prompt, I don't see any output but my emails aren't sent:

```
php /home../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php -s [site] -u [user] -p [password] -a execute -e Job
```

I also tried the URL version and that didn't work either.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Here is my version info:

```
PHP 5.3.27 (cli) (built: Jan  2 2014 07:19:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.4.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by ionCube Ltd., and
    with Zend Guard Loader v3.3, Copyright (c) 1998-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: Are you running "/home../public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php" literally, or is it the actual path to cli.php?  Similarly, are you replacing [site], [user], and [password]?

Comment: @Andrew: no, it is the correct command, with replaced values for those variables. It turned out I had to give a specific job, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but when I specifically ran the email job it worked.

Comment: Xodarap: We're close to launching a CiviCRM specific StackExhange site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77367/civicrm. We've got enough committers, and they are active enough, but we need 8 more people with over 200 reputation on a different StackExchange site to 'commit' to the proposal. Would you be willing to do that for us and the community of people needing good answers to good CiviCRM questions? Thx